# Issue in iteration over JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Below is the JSON structure :

```
{
    "action": "organizationQueryResponse",
    "status": "SUCCESS",
    "matchCount": "2",
    "organizationDetailsList": [
            {
                "organizationDetails": {
                    "organizationID": "xxxxx",
                    "organizationName": "xxxx",
                    "parentOpCoName": "yyyy",
                    "registeredEmailID": "zzzz",
                    "registeredPhoneNo": "xxxx"
                }
            },
            {
                "organizationDetails": {                  
                    "organizationID": "xxxxx",
                    "organizationName": "xxxx",
                    "parentOpCoName": "yyyy",
                    "registeredEmailID": "zzzz",
                    "registeredPhoneNo": "xxxx"

                }
            }        
    ]
}
```

All I need is the values corresponding to *organizationDetails* key and append these values in a `<tr>`. I tried it, but always ended up with a messy code. Please help in writing a jQuery function for the same.

This is what I was trying.

```
success : function(response) {                   
            //process response here
            alert('Success !!!');

            $.each(response, function(key,val){
                if(key == 'organizationDetailsList'){
                    $.each(val, function(keys,vals){
                        $.each(vals, function(keys,values){
                            alert("key : "+keys+" ; value : "+values);
                        });                 
                    });                 
                }
            });
            }
```

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: Your code may be messy, however we need to see it in order to educate you about how to improve it. Sure, someone can spoonfeed you the answer but you learn absolutely nothing, and will just be back again when you encounter the same issue in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/jLr5vapn/

```js
var data = {
    "action": "organizationQueryResponse",
    "status": "SUCCESS",
    "matchCount": "2",
    "organizationDetailsList": [
            {
                "organizationDetails": {
                    "organizationID": "xxxxx",
                    "organizationName": "xxxx",
                    "parentOpCoName": "yyyy",
                    "registeredEmailID": "zzzz",
                    "registeredPhoneNo": "xxxx"
                }
            },
            {
                "organizationDetails": {                  
                    "organizationID": "xxxxx",
                    "organizationName": "xxxx",
                    "parentOpCoName": "yyyy",
                    "registeredEmailID": "zzzz",
                    "registeredPhoneNo": "xxxx"

                }
            }        
    ]
};

// ----- getting the header
var headHTML = "<thead>";

var html = "<tbody>";

// ----- getting the row data
$.each(data.organizationDetailsList, function(i){
 html += "<tr>";
  if(i === 0)
   headHTML += "<tr>";
   $.each(data.organizationDetailsList[i].organizationDetails, function(key){
     html += "<td>" + data.organizationDetailsList[i].organizationDetails[key] + "</td>";
      
      if(i === 0){
       headHTML+= "<th>" + key + "</th>";
      }
    });
  html += "<tr>";
  
  if(i === 0)
   headHTML += "</tr></thead>";
});

html += "</tbody>"

$('table').append(headHTML, html);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>

</table>
```

I have taken your sample JSON data & created a table out of it.
I have used **$.each** whatever you are using & just created the html out of that loop and **appended** it to the table.

**Header** is also created out of that **$.each** when **i** value is **0**.